# How do I obtain developer items?

Tags: terraria

Redigit said on stream that in the new expert mode there'd be a way to obtain all the developer items. Unfortunately I am at work right now, so I'd like to know, how do I obtain developer gear and items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/3br28o/spoilers_after_countless_hours_of_grinding_i/), the hard mode bosses will drop Treasure Bags that can contain Developer gear.